# HTML Input Blank Value Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a simple login form that just won't start with blank values, no matter what I do (even after adding JavaScript).

**Code**

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="login.php" method="post">
    <div class="fields-search">
        <input type="text" id="wf_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="" name="wf_username" title="Required" required>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            document.getElementById("wf_username").value=""; 
        </script>
        <input type="password" id="wf_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="" name="wf_password" title="Required" required>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            document.getElementById("wf_password").value=""; 
        </script>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="formsubmit" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>
</form>
```

But it always shows this:
[image]

I don't know if that's my MAMP MySQL password showing, but it's disturbing. In every other form where I've used `value=""` it works fine - what gives here?

I have cleared my cache and tried Chrome & FF - same behaviour. But Safari seems to work fine (Chrome & FF work fine for my other forms where I've set `value=""`, though)

**Edit**
I added the autocomplete attribute to both inputs but same result.

```
        <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="login.php" method="post">
            <div class="fields-search"> 
                <input type="text" id="wf_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="" name="wf_username" title="Required" autocomplete="off" required>
                    <script type="text/javascript"> 
                        document.getElementById("wf_username").value=""; 
                    </script>
                <input type="password" id="wf_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="" name="wf_password" title="Required" autocomplete="off" required>
                    <script type="text/javascript"> 
                        document.getElementById("wf_password").value=""; 
                    </script>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" id="formsubmit" class="btn btn-success">
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Edit 3**
Autocomplete doesn't work when there is an input of type 'password'. Looks like Chrome & FF will autofill that and then an adjacent text box with a username from its saved user/pswd info. This DID work:

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="login.php" method="post">
    <div class="fields-search"> 
        <input type="text" id="wf_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="" name="wf_username" style="background:none" title="Required" autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) {this.removeAttribute('readonly');
                                this.blur(); this.focus(); }" autofocus required>
        <input type="password" id="wf_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="" name="wf_password" style="background:none" title="Required" autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) {this.removeAttribute('readonly');
                                this.blur(); this.focus(); }"  required>
        <div align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" id="formsubmit" class="btn btn-danger"
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: did you try adding `autocomplete="off"`?

Comment: Are these auto completed form values given by your browser? If not how are you populating those values?

Comment: Spencer - I don't know how the values are getting there. Only happens in Chrome & FF (haven't tried IE)

Comment: Idg - see my edit. No change.

Comment: j08691 is right - the solution is in the dupe he selected. I implemented the fix from dsuess (adding the styling suggestion from  Arnis Juraga to keep the background normal) and it worked.

Comment: See _all_ the answers in the duplicate.

Comment: I did read the whole page, but what worked for me was what I said in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. Use the `autocomplete="off"` attribute on your inputs

Comment: bukharim96 - see my edit. No change.